# Error when installing Async CTP1

Tags: async-ctp

Whenevern I try to install Async CTP1 I get the[image] message popup

Can someone help with this?

Comment: tried pressing OK? It's a warning, not an error...

Comment: Now why would Microsoft do something like thiS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sonpther others(sees-may find iterator may know where it's at. Turns outfit's a warning not a problem